# Which program/code can overlay different graphical elements and create new image.png files algorithmically?

Tags: image, image-processing, graphics, imagemagick, cimg

I have 10 different graphical shapes, 10 different colors and 10 different sizes and want to make every possible combination with each other. As doing those 1000 manually is impossible I'm looking for an algorithm that can do this for me. Is there a program or some kind of library that I can feed the constraints to and that puts out image.png files for me?

So far I've found CImg and Magick++ but not sure if that's a good solution.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This site does not serve as general problem solving portal. The community will help you to get a working solution, but you should share your code with images showing what you have done already that did not work. Read "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), "What are good topics" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and "How do I ask a good question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? 
What do you mean by making every possible combination?  How do you want to combine the shapes?

Comment: ImageMagick can do a lot in an efficient manner. It can also be scripted.

Comment: If I understand your question, you can make a list (or array) of your shapes and of your colors and of your sizes. Then write 3 nested loops over each one of those and create every possible combination and save them as PNG in ImageMagick. The scripting depends upon OS (Linux/Mac OSX or Windows). How are your shapes defined? Please provide sample of the shapes and an output.

Comment: Scripting is different on Windows from Linux/Unix-based operating systems, so kindly say what you can use.

Comment: Got it, will take note for the next time. Thanks a lot for the quick reply, I managed to write a batch script on Windows using ImageMagick and got some really good results already. So I think I'll be ok from here. Only as a general question, is batch a solid solution for scripting such applications or is something else recommended?

Comment: Depends upon your OS. .bat scripts are Windows specific. On Unix (Linux, Mac OSX) I typically use bash shell scripts. Alternately, you can code in Python Wand, which uses ImageMagick, or Python OpenCV.

Comment: Let's say BATCH scripts probably aren't the most highly regarded... http://blog.nullspace.io/batch.html

Comment: @fmw42 My solution works offline, but as an addition, I'd like to use cloud computation for doing this. I know that ImageMagick can be used with Firebase Functions (Google cloud computation), so I guess I should be able to create a link that passes the 3 params (color, size, shape) to the cloud, graphically constructs the image, and returns the file to the caller, correct?